# HPV 51 positive male - how to avoid cancer?

Tags: virus, cancer, hpv

From what I know:

- HPV 51 is considered carcinogenic
- There is currently no reliable method to completely cure it

What can be done to mitigate the risks?

How to detect cancer development?

Are any actions required if there are no visible condylomata?

Also, is there any statistical data on how often HPV 51 causes cancer in males?